# Word frequencies in Python instead of listing

Tags: python, keras

I have the following code:

```
from keras.preprocessing import text

with open('engl_bible.txt', 'r') as file:
norm_bible = file

tokenizer = text.Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(norm_bible)

word2id = tokenizer.word_index
id2word = {v:k for k, v in word2id.items()}

vocab_size = len(word2id) + 1
embed_size = 100

wids = [[word2id[w] for w in text.text_to_word_sequence(doc)] for doc in norm_bible]

print('Vocabulary Size:', vocab_size)
```

print('Vocabulary Sample:', list(word2id.items())[:10])

This leads to following output:

```
Vocabulary Size: 3847
Vocabulary Sample: [('and', 1), ('the', 2), ('to', 3), ('of', 4), ('you', 5), ('he', 6), ('in', 7), ('a', 8), ('is', 9), ('him', 10)]
```

But it should create something comparable to (so not a ranking of 1 to 10, but with word frequencies) :

```
Vocabulary Size: 12425
Vocabulary Sample: [('perceived', 1460), ('flagon', 7287), ('gardener', 11641), ('named', 973), ('remain', 732), ('sticketh', 10622), ('abstinence', 11848), ('rufus', 8190), ('adversary', 2018), ('jehoiachin', 3189)]
```

I really can't figure out what went wrong, hope you can help me! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

if you want the word frequencies you need to use `tokenizer.word_counts` and not `tokenizer.word_index`.
So the code will be:

```
from keras.preprocessing import text

with open('engl_bible.txt', 'r') as file:
    norm_bible = file

    tokenizer = text.Tokenizer()
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(norm_bible)

    word2id = tokenizer.word_counts
    id2word = {v:k for k, v in word2id.items()}

    vocab_size = len(word2id) + 1
    embed_size = 100

    wids = [[word2id[w] for w in text.text_to_word_sequence(doc)] for doc in norm_bible]

    print('Vocabulary Size:', vocab_size)
    print('Vocabulary Sample:', list(word2id.items())[:10])
```

pay attention though that now `word2id` isn't really word2id but rather `word2frequency`...